# How is the second differential non-zero?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I'm trying to work through an example of a non-degenerate critical point of a single variable function using the $k$-form definition of a differential as given in Spivak's calculus on manifolds, and I'm having some trouble applying it.

In the book on singularity theory, the critical point is non-degenerate at some point $x$ if the second differential of the function at $x$ is a non-degenerate quadratic form.  However, suppose we start of with the first differential
$$df=D_1f\cdot dx^1$$
which is a $1$-form.  If we now take the differential to turn this into a $2$-form, it seems to me that from the identity $d(d\omega)=0$ that the second differential is always zero.  I should be able to determine the degeneracy of a critical point based on this definition, but this would seem to imply that all critical points are degenerate, which clearly is not true.

However, an alternate path which seems to work would be to use
$$d\omega=\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_k}\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}D_\alpha(\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_k})\cdot dx^\alpha\wedge dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_k}$$
to obtain
$$d(df)=D_1^2f\cdot dx^1\wedge dx^1$$
which would be non-zero.  However this seems to contradict with the identity $d(d\omega)=0$.

1. What is the difference between the two cases?
2. What have I misunderstood about $k$-forms?
3. Is this the correct method for analysing the degeneracy of functions using $k$-forms?

Comment: @AnneBauval but in the one dimensional case, wouldn't the "Hessian" in this case be zero?  The example I'm looking at specifically is $f(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=x^3$, where $x^2$ is degenerate but $x^3$ is not.  I've got a separate question which answers why one of them is degenerate, but it doesn't use the definition in Spivak, and I'm trying to reach the same conclusion using Spivak's definition.

Comment: @AnneBauval so what is the difference between the $2$-form $d(df)$ and the second differential?  I would have thought that to get the second differential you find the differential of the first differential $df$.  What is the difference between the two ideas?

Comment: @AnneBauval so does that mean that a "second differential" is a different object from the $k$-form differential?  It seems that since its symmetric it is something distinct from a $k$-form.  How will I know if a differential being referenced in a text is talking about $k$-forms or something else?

Comment: @AnneBauval great do you want to write all that as an answer and I can give it a tick so the question is resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$dx_i∧dx_j=−dxj∧dxi$ (in particular, $dx_i∧dx_i=0$). When applying twice on $f$ the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#The_exterior_derivative) $d,$ you obtain $0$ because of [Schwarz-Clairaut's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives). However, the (therefore symmetric) [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) is not necessarily $0.$

Even in the one dimensional case, $f′(x_0)=0$ does not imply $f′′(x_0)=0$ (i.e. the Hessian is not necessarily $0$), as [your example $x^2$ shows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613884). Spivak's second differential is nothing else than the Hessian. It is not the (zero) $2$-form $d(df).$

For a $2$-form $ω$ at some point $x,$ $ω(x)$ is an *alternate* bilinear form on $T_xM.$ Whereas the second differential (or Hessian) $D^2f(x)$ is a *symmetric* bilinear form on $T_xM.$

When talking about the second differential of $f$ it will most often be $D^2f,$ not $d^2f=0.$ The distinct notation also helps to differentiate [pun intended] them.